# Child class is not inheriting parent class variable

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I am new to selenium. I tried to create a automate testing project. In there I created  class for every web pages and in my test packages  I created a baseTest class where I initiate browser and open the home page and another class for other methods.I also created test classes for every pages. Now when I move into homepages the driver is null.but every testclass extends baseTest.Why is it happening?

```
package utilities;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver;

public class utility {
    public WebDriver udriver;
    
    public void setDriver(WebDriver driver)
    {
        udriver =driver;
    }
    
    public String getTitle() {
        return udriver.getTitle();
        
    }
    
    public void clickEl(WebElement element) {
        element.click();
    }

}
```

homePageClass

```
package Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

import utilities.utility;

public class HomePage extends utility {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[normalize-space()='Gmail']")
    WebElement gmailBtn;

    public String homePageTitle() {
        return getTitle();
    }

    public void clickOnGmailBtn() {
        clickEl(gmailBtn);
    }

}
```

baseTest

```
package tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import utilities.utility;

public class BaseTest {
    protected WebDriver driver;
    utility utility =new utility();
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void initializeBrowser()
    {
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        utility.setDriver(driver);
        
    }
    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown(){
        driver.quit();
    
    }
}
```

TestHomePage

```
package tests;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Pages.HomePage;
import utilities.utility;

public class TestHomePage extends utility{
    HomePage homePage= new HomePage();
    @Test
    public void TilteTest() {
    
        System.out.println(homePage.homePageTitle());
    }

}
```

I tried with create a utility instance before every method ,but didn't work. I hope that the driver form crated in baseTest class will be passed to utility class and evry webPage class will get access to it.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you need to make the driver static in the Utility class.

```
public class Utility {
   public static WebDriver udriver;

   public static void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
      udriver = driver;
   }
}
```